# Can Poly2Tri triangulate polygons with collinear points?

Tags: c#, .net, triangulation

I'm trying to triangulate the following rectangular polygon with multiple points on the bottom and top edges, [Poly2Tri](http://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/) C# implementation fails to triangulate it properly. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
[0.624999999999412,0.549725]:{3914247097}
[0.624999999999412,0.0499749999999999]:{2649576031} 
[0.697622146677862,0.0499749999999999]:{3234442680}
[0.764780181168915,0.0499749999999999]:{779801897} 
[0.83091206956133,0.0499749999999999]:{3290577852} 
[0.900187283173112,0.0499749999999999]:{965350020} 
[0.974812716825783,0.0499749999999999]:{4158962073} 
[1.04408793043765,0.0499749999999999]:{2500807069} 
[1.11021981883008,0.0499749999999999]:{1609890243} 
[1.17737785332108,0.0499749999999999]:{4031413118}
[1.25,0.0499749999999999]:{1430088023} 
[1.25,0.549725]:{133402941} 
[1.17737785332114,0.549725]:{1740221683} 
[1.11021981883019,0.549725]:{2812201862} 
[1.04408793043782,0.549725]:{1792339566} 
[0.97481271682603,0.549725]:{2861752679} 
[0.900187283173419,0.549725]:{3438312411}
[0.83091206956167,0.549725]:{3605485935} 
[0.764780181169306,0.549725]:{3777559811}
[0.69762214667833,0.549725]:{1274513046}}
```

Comment: This is json, not c#.  You need to de-serialize the data in jason.

Comment: ? These are simply the 2D point coordinates as long with it hash value.

Comment: Having square brackets with colon's are jason.  You need to use a Jason reader, not a c# reader.

Comment: The C++ version of poly2tri worked fine with this data.